# Как найти все даты в тексте?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, дата

В тексте мне необходимо найти все даты. Даты могут быть записаны в разных форматах - 19 января, 19 января 2020 года, 19.01, 19.01.2020, 19.01.20, 19/01, 19/01/2020, 19.01/20, через неделю, завтра, послезавтра и т.п.

Сделал следующий regex, но почему-то все даты не ловит -

```
regex = ur"([012]?\d (января|февраля|марта|апреля|мая|июня|июля|августа|сентября|октября|ноября|декабря))|([012]?\d[.\/\\][01]?\d)|(завтра|послезавтра)"
contest_date = re.findall(regex, text)
```

Где я ошибся?

Comment: ну для начала - пример входных данных дайте и то что он находит, а то пальцем в небо не особо тыкать, и еще есть ресурс для чека регулярок, очень годный https://regex101.com/

Comment: Можно попробовать библиотеку [natasha](https://github.com/natasha/natasha)

Comment: Что не находит? Приведите примеры.